# Finding all shortest paths from source to all vertices in a digraph

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, shortest-path, directed-graph

We are given a directed graph G (possibly with cycles) with positive edge weights, and the minimum distance `D[v]` to every vertex `v` from a source s is also given (D is an array this way).
The problem is to find the array `N[v] = number` of paths of length `D[v]` from s to v,
in linear time.

Now this is a homework problem that I've been struggling with for quite long. I was working along the following thought : I'm trying to remove the cycles by suitably choosing an acyclic subgraph of G, and then try to find shortest paths from s to v in the subgraph.

But I cannot figure out explicitly what to do, so I'd appreciate any help, as in a qualitative idea on what to do.

Comment: Note that if you add a restriction "simple paths" You can reduce Hamiltonian path problem into it, by simply sending `D=[n,n,...,n]`. This is a good *intuition* usually that the problem itself is also NPC, unless you have missed a few restrictions on the graph structure.

Comment: @amit, D[v] is a shortest path distance (from s to v) not arbitrary distance (and is given).

Comment: @SaeedAmiri Not sure I am following then. The shortest distance is given, and all you have to do is find how many shortest paths are there?

Comment: @amit, I guess so, as I can read it says so. (seems it's just a counting problem)

Comment: @amit : Yes, the shortest distance from s is given for all vertices. And we have to find number of shortest paths from s to v, but for each v.

Comment: @UrysohnLemma, Is it your D array sorted or not?

Comment: @SaeedAmiri : No. We've just arbitrarily labeled vertices 0, 1, 2, ... and their respective shortest dist's are D[0], D[1], ...

Answer (score 3):

You can use [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) approach in here, and fill up the number of paths as you go, if `D[u] + w(u,v) = D[v]`, something like:

```
N = [0,...,0]
N[s] = 1 //empty path
For each vertex v, in *ascending* order of `D[v]`:
   for each edge (u,v) such that D[u] < D[v]:
       if D[u] + w(u,v) = D[v]: //just found new shortest paths, using (u,v)!
           N[v] += N[u]
```

Complexity is `O(VlogV + E)`, assuming the graph is not sparsed, `O(E)` is dominanting.

---

**Explanation:**

If there is a shortest path `v0->v1->...->v_(k-1)->v_k` from `v0` to `v_k`, then `v0->...->v_(k-1)` is a shortest path from `v0` to `v_k-1`, thus - when iterating `v_k` - `N[v_(k-1)]` was already computed fully (remember, all edges have positive weights, and `D[V_k-1] < D[v_k]`, and we are iterating by increasing value of `D[v]`).

Therefor, the path `v0->...->v_(k-1)` is counted in the number `N[V_(k-1)]` at this point.

Since `v0->...->v_(k-1)-v_k` is a shortest path - it means `D[v_(k-1)] + w(v_k-1,v_k) = D[v_k]` - thus the condition will hold, and we will add the count of this path to `N[v_k]`.

Note that the proof for this algorithm will basically be induction that will follow the guidelines from this explanation more formally.

Comment: Although this is an elegant solution, won't it be non-linear if it's a sparse graph? I also think dynamic programming may be involved, but a strictly linear algorithm is required...

Comment: Isn't there anything along the lines of finding a suitable subgraph, etc. , the approach I mentioned in the question? (after working for so long on the problem I'm hoping something involving this method may work)

Comment: @UrysohnLemma None that I can think of, usually things involving finding subgraphs is a hard problem (MST is obvious exception to the statement), but I have no clue if it is also the case here.

Comment: This is not an O(n) in any sense (works just for a very sparse graphs). (e.g when I asked whether the input is sorted or not, I was thinking for a way to get rid of log n factor).

Comment: @SaeedAmiri If the graph is not sparsed, it is linear in the *size of the input*, which is the graph. [note that the OP is asking for linear, not linear with n]

Comment: Even in sparse case is not O(n), and my comment for OP was for this (and I could not come up with O(n) algorithm), Also about the linear time problem in graph-theory, is usually means linear to size of graph (not input), and size of graph is defined by the number of its vertices.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri I disagree. BFS is considered linear, and is O(V+E).

Comment: @amit, I disagree, not really, if you claim that your BFS is linear, you should prove that your graph is sparse or your BFS skips something, otherwise you can not say is linear you can say is linear to the number of edges and number of vertices, but you should not say is linear. but may be this homework question is in non-standard format, and they are not looking for elegant way.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri Let's agree to disagree, but according to [berkley lecture notes](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/s99cs170/notes/lec13.pdf): `Breadth-first search runs, of course, in **linear time**, O(|E|) ...` Guess the definition is ambigious regarding it, I see no point to keep this discussion going.

Comment: I agree to disagree, but be precise on my comment, I said when you say is linear (alone, without anything), you should say is linear because ..., or you can say is linear to number of edges + number of vertices, and even Berkly lectures says is linear to E, (and says why they didn't said is linear to V). (I agree to be disagree). P.S: I didn't say you made mistake, I said by my understanding from question, your answer is not that desired linear.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on how/why this works? I think it may fail if you have 0->2->1->3, where 0,1,2,3 are vertices corresponding to the same indices in `D` (assume you have 0->1->2->4 and 3->4 to motivate an ordering of 0,1,2,3,4). You will never check 2->1, thus never get this shortest path. Also, aren't you missing an `else if D[u] + w(u,v) < D[v] ....`, or is that not possible; if not, why not?

Comment: @Dukeling added an explanation. I do not understand your example, if you can formulate it better i'll try to add an example step to step to the answer as well.